# Decrementing while loop in c

Tags: c, while-loop

Is it possible to decrement the array size in a while loop in C by more than `x--`.  For example, can you decrement an array by a third of the array size with each iteration?

```
int n = 10;

while (n < 0)

// do something

(round(n/3))-- // this doesn't work, but can this idea be expressed in C?
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by *decrement array*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any expression:

```
int n = 10;
while (n > 0)   // Note change compared with original!
{
    // Do something
    n = round(n/3.0) - 1;  // Note assignment and floating point
}
```

Note that you can only decrement variables, not expressions.

You could also use a `for` loop:

```
for (int n = 10; n > 0; n = round(n/3.0) - 1)
{
    // Do something
}
```

In this case, the sequence of values for `n` will be the same (`n = 10, 2`) whether you round using floating point or not, so you could write:

```
n = n / 3 - 1;
```

and you'd see the same results.  For other upper limits, the sequence would change (`n = 11, 3`).  Both techniques are fine, but you need to be sure you know what you want, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to add or subtract any number to your variable `n`.

Usually, if you want to do something a very predictable number of times, you would use a `for` loop; when you aren't sure how many times something will happen, but rather you are testing some sort of condition, you use a `while` loop.

The rarest loop is a `do` / `while` loop, which is only used when you want to execute a loop one time for certain before the first time the `while` check occurs.

Examples:

```
// do something ten times
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    do_something();

// do something as long as user holds down button
while (button_is_pressed())
    do_something();

// play a game, then find out if user wants to play again
do
{
    char answer;
    play_game();
    printf("Do you want to play again?  Answer 'y' to play again, anything else to exit. ");
    answer = getchar();
} while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no array in your code. If you wan't `n` to have a third of its value on each iteration, you can do `n /= 3;`. Note that since `n` is integral then the integral division is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Just like K-Ballo said there is no array in your example code but here is an example with an integer array.

```
int n = 10;
int array[10];
int result;

// Fill up the array with some values
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    array[i] = i+n;

while(n > 0)
{
    // Do something with array

    n -= sizeof(array)/3;
}
```

But be careful in the example code you gave the while loop is checking if n is less than zero. As n is intialised to 10 the while loop will never be executed. I have changed it in my example.